# Should the Http response include the password?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

Everything is in the title.

After a successfully post request to create a user, should I include the password in the response ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Password goes the only one way, from user to server and never comes back. Actually after user is created, you should not posses password as plain text anymore. It should be hashed by BCrypt or other secure hashing function and stored in database.

Even though password would be hashed you should never send it to the client (browser)